# Read it Later slide with CSS3 and HTML5 or JS

Tags: javascript, mobile, css

does any one know how to make the slide to left effect like in the "Read it Later" app with CSS3 or JS?

onclick --> slide whole div to left and show the div under the one which slides away.

here is an video with the example: [READ IT LATER](http://cl.ly/122a361f3y0c3b3s1C1o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be that's you want with css3. 
**CSS**

```
.parent{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.box{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:green;
    display:block;
    z-index:0;
}
.slider{
    width:300px;
    background:#454545;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:300px;
    transition: right 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 1s ease; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:right 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:right 1s ease; /* Opera */
    z-index:1;
}
.box:focus + .slider,.box:active + .slider{
    right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="box"></a>
    <div class="slider">hello</div>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MhHx2/

**UPDATED**

http://jsfiddle.net/MhHx2/4/

Comment: ok. thats nearly perfect. the Hello Box just needs to slide right without keeping the other box pressed. Means: press green box --> slide right grey box. touch grey box --> slide left grey box

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that effect by using a couple of standard techniques.

1. Create two `div` elements, one for the one that is going to slide out, and one for the one that is going to get revealed.
2. Position them using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). Please not that the `div`s have to be positioned using `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed` for this to work.
3. You can use jQuery for the effects. I found a decent post [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/).

That should get you done.

Comment: alright. thanks for the tip. i get this done for one single div. but if i would like to have a list of 4 to 5 sliders, i do not know how to do this in jquery. how do i trigger every time the same effect in each div/slider?

Comment: @Max, can you be a bit more specific? For multiple `div`s, just repeat the same, with z-indexes stacked up. For instance, 4 `div` elements with z-indexes 1 to 4 will be stacked one on top of the other. Now that we've taken care of the stacking part, you can have a `var current` to keep a track of which `div` is on top. Use jQuery to move that particular `div` on, say, a buttonclick. I hope that clears it up.